# GDB define command: print $arg1 doesn't print the correct value when in define

Tags: gdb, gdbinit

I want to define a new command which basically sets a breakpoint on a line, print a value of a certain variable and then continues execution. Unfortunately I am having issues. Here is the code I am using

```
(gdb) define print_and_continue
Type commands for definition of "print_and_continue".
End with a line saying just "end".
>break $arg0
>command $bpnum
 >print $arg1
 >continue
 >end
>end
```

So I want to print the value of variable `len` which is defined in `linked_list.h:109`. And I execute the following code:

```
(gdb) print_and_continue linked_list.h:111 len
Breakpoint 1 at 0x388a: linked_list.h:111. (12 locations)
(gdb) r
...

Breakpoint 1, linked_list<test_struct<1>, 1>::remove_if<run_test<1, 1, 1>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)::{lambda(test_struct<1> const&)#1}>(run_test<1, 1, 1>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)::{lambda(test_struct<1> const&)#1}&&) (this=0x7fffffffdca0, condition=...) at linked_list.h:112
112         linked_list_node* prev = nullptr;
$1 = void
```

It seems like `$arg1` in `print` function didn't get replaces by the actual argument. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like $arg1 in print function didn't get replaces by the actual argument.

I don't believe that's what is actually happening. Rather, everything following `command $bpnum` is attached to the newly-created breakpoint literally (without any expansion at all). You can see that happening with `info break`, which will show something like:

```
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x0000000000001136 at ...
        print $arg1
        continue
```

This is generally what you would want (deferring evaluating the argument until the time breakpoint is hit). Otherwise you would print *current* value of `len` if you use `print len`, when what you want is to print the value of `len` when the breakpoint is hit.

Of course, when the breakpoint is hit, there is no `$arg1` (or `$arg0`) anywhere around, so you get the same output you'd get trying to print any other non-existent GDB variable.

> What am I doing wrong?

You are using "quick hack of a language" (which is what the "native" GDB scripting language is), instead of using a proper programming language.

I am 99.99% certain that defining `print_and_continue` is possible (and probably quite easy) using [embedded Python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html).

That said, I don't believe that `print_and_continue` is all that useful (in my 20+ years of using GDB, I *never* needed anything like that).